# connection already null in cleanup : no action

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to update my object using hibernate like this

NB : [ the object ProduitsVendus have two objects as attributs (produit and client)

why the update method is not applied on my data ?

```
public void modifierproduitVendusSelectionner( ProduitsVendus pv) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.merge(pv);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }
```

and before this method I call this one

```
@Override
public ProduitsVendus recupererProduitVenduParId(Long id) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    ProduitsVendus c = null;
    Query q = session.createQuery("from ProduitsVendus where pk_seq = '" + id + "'");
    c = (ProduitsVendus) q.uniqueResult();
    return c;
}
```

this is a capture of a part of my logs hibernate

```
14:59:53,968 DEBUG DefaultLoadEventListener:349 - resolved object in session cache: [com.kdi.models.Produit#1]
14:59:53,968 DEBUG TwoPhaseLoad:209 - done materializing entity [com.kdi.models.ProduitsVendus#3]
14:59:53,969 DEBUG TwoPhaseLoad:111 - resolving associations for [com.kdi.models.ProduitsVendus#4]
14:59:53,969 DEBUG DefaultLoadEventListener:171 - loading entity: [com.kdi.models.Client#1]
14:59:53,969 DEBUG DefaultLoadEventListener:332 - attempting to resolve: [com.kdi.models.Client#1]
14:59:53,969 DEBUG DefaultLoadEventListener:349 - resolved object in session cache: [com.kdi.models.Client#1]
14:59:53,969 DEBUG DefaultLoadEventListener:171 - loading entity: [com.kdi.models.Produit#1]
14:59:53,970 DEBUG DefaultLoadEventListener:332 - attempting to resolve: [com.kdi.models.Produit#1]
14:59:53,970 DEBUG DefaultLoadEventListener:349 - resolved object in session cache: [com.kdi.models.Produit#1]
14:59
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why the update method is not applied on my data ?